# Principal of Analog to digital converter(ADC) and Digital to analog converter(DAC)

Tags: adc, dac, basic

Analog to digital converter is one that converts analog output form sensors to digital one what are basic principal of **Analog to digital converter(ADC)** and the opposite of one that takes digital input and provides analog value the  **Digital to analog converter(DAC)**?How can we explain it using a simple example?
I had a look at following but would it be explained in better way:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter
- [google books](http://books.google.com.np/books?id=m5NYbUpqXY0C&pg=PA165&dq=principal%20of%20Analog%20to%20digital%20converter&hl=ne&ei=HdLSTpi8NILSrQfCn8XBDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: This is pretty unspecific, it might draw the closers..

Comment: The internet is so very very very very full of superb examples of this that referring you to a search engine as a starting point is not the impoliteness that such responses are sometimes seen to be. [[ie Jargon = LMGTFY]. In cases such as this far less of YOUR time is taken in searching than in others time replying AND you get any of a large number of superb example.  Have a search and read, come back an ask questions if unsure of what you find.  read

Comment: Answer added. Whether you ever get to read its introduction depends on whether you are faster than the thought police :-)

Comment: @Russell McMahon Thanks! "Faster than the though police" refers to? I guess I need to post new thread asking this!! :D

Comment: You beat them! :-). The 1st paragraph telling people to look on the web in selected cases seems to be demmed unacceptable in all cases. Strangely.

Comment: @Russell stackexchange is designed to be the source of info. There is no value if an answer is only linking or telling someone to go else where. However since you actually included content in your answer, it isn't as big of deal.

Answer (score 6):

There are many many many many excellent existing on web tutorials on this.The following are excellent examples BUT you should have a look around as much has been written that will improve your general understanding far more than having people spell out again something which is so well covered elsewhere.

This one gives a better than some concise explanation of 3 types of ADCs complete with flow chart where apposite. [Remarkably compact explanations](http://230nsc1.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/adc.html)  but easily enough followed with only a basic grasp of electronics, if that.

The same people also offer this [superb introduction to digital to analog conversion](http://230nsc1.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/dac.html#c1).

---

**From the above pages:**
Successive Approximation ADC

Note that a DAC is used in the ADC :-) -  see DAC below.

Illustration of 4-bit SAC with 1 volt step size (after Tocci, Digital Systems).

The successive approximation ADC is much faster than the digital ramp ADC because it uses digital logic to converge on the value closest to the input voltage. A comparator and a DAC are used in the process.

[image]

[image]

---

- **Four-Bit D/A Converter**

One way to achieve D/A conversion is to use a summing amplifier.

This approach is not satisfactory for a large number of bits because it requires too much precision in the summing resistors. This problem is overcome in the R-2R network DAC.

[image]

__

- **R-2R Ladder DAC**

The summing amplifier with the R-2R ladder of resistances shown produces the output

where the D's take the value 0 or 1. The digital inputs could be TTL voltages which close the switches on a logical 1 and leave it grounded for a logical 0. This is illustrated for 4 bits, but can be extended to any number with just the resistance values R and 2R.

[image]

Comment: I had a look at these tutorials but they are less explanatory but have rather nice images!

Answer (score 4):

They do what the names say.

A *analog to digital* converter produces a digital number from a voltage.  This is usually binary, so the A/D converter is rated in the number of bits.  A 8 bit A/D, for example, divides the input voltage range into 256 slots and tells you which one the voltage is in.  There are quite a few different ways to achieve this.  Some common ones you should be able to easily look up are called "successive approximation", "delta-sigma", and "flash converter".

A *digital to analog* converter does the reverse.  You give it a binary number and it produces a voltage proportional to that number.  There are multiple ways to achieve this too, but by far the largest group of these use something called a "R-2R ladder" one way or the other internally.  Another way that may not be a true D/A but can nonetheless eventually result in a analog voltage from a digital value is a PWM generator.  It produces a stream of pulses at a fixed frequency, but the width of the pulses is adjusted digitally.  After low pass filtering, the resulting analog value is proportional to the pulse width divided by the pulse period.  This ratio is often referred to as the "duty cycle".